# Cypress Uploading

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

```
describe ('Upload Test' , function(){
    it('Upload Test' , function(){
        cy.visit('https://document.online-convert.com/convert/csv-to-excel')
        cy.get('#fileUploadButton').click()
        const catalogue ='../integration/Example.csv';
        cy.get('#file').attachFile(catalogue);
        cy.get('#multifile-submit-button-main').click()
    })
})
```

i tried to upload the csv file and click on convert it, At cypress test result it shows that the file have been uploaded but actually its not.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gehBB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're using [cypress-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload). Your file seems to be in the integration folder. I would suggest putting all the files required for Cypress tests inside cypress/fixtures folder and calling them as fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

I would also higly suggest to use [cypress-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload).

With it you can do it like that:

First, you get your input field for the file. Then you can use .attachFile to declare the source and give it a name

```
cy.get('.FileInput input[type=file]')
 .attachFile({filePath: 'Example.csv', fileName});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of events attached to the input that need to be fired after you attach the file.

The user will click the "Choose file" and the OS opens a file selection dialog. Since Cypress can't control that dialog, you are effective replacing that step with `.attachFile(...)`.

As soon as the file is attached, the upload begins automatically and when complete, the file name appears in the file list element.

The element we need to attach to is `<input id="fileUploadInput" type="file">`.

If you inspect this element, and look at it's event listeners there's a `change` event and a custom event `fileuploadsubmit` that look useful

This is the code that works for me

```js
const catalogue = "../fixtures/example.csv";
cy.get('#fileUploadInput')
  .attachFile(catalogue)

// this just confirms the internal file property of the element
// i.e confirm the attachFile worked
// You can leave it out, it does not affect the process
cy.get('#fileUploadInput')
  .its('0.files')        
  .its('0')              
  .its('name')           
  .should('eq', 'example.csv')

// Now trigger the change event
cy.get('#fileUploadInput')
  .trigger('change', {force:true})  // force because the input is hidden

// And the fileuploadsubmit event 
// Note that after change event, the input is detached from DOM
// so we need to re-query for the id
cy.get('#fileUploadInput')  
  .trigger('fileuploadsubmit', {force:true})

// Confirm the file is in the file list
// if it's a large file, allow enough time with a timeout option
cy.contains('span', 'example.csv', {timeout: 10000}) 

// Now start the conversion
cy.get('#multifile-submit-button-main').click()
```